# Error Receiving broadcast Intent notification

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I'm getting this error in log cat when i receive a notification but not always. Seems that sometimes the String i want pass and display in a toast results `null` but not always. The error is this as from title:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=it.dd.notification flg=0x10 (has extras) }
--
--
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f04006b
--
at it.dd.notification.Main$2.onReceive(Main.java:417)
--
```

i can't post all logCat because i don't have Eclipse here. I remember this parts that are what i need to understand the problem.
I declared these first in MainActivity:

```
//private String dir;
protected MyReceiver mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    public static String INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION = "it.dd.notification";
    private String titoloNoti;
    private String contenutoNoti;
    //
```

Always in MainActivity i have this BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent != null) {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                String notificationTitle = extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
                CharSequence notificationText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);

                contenutoNoti = notificationText.toString(); //Line 417

                Toast loc = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contenutoNoti, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                loc.show();

            }

        }
    }
```

So when i intercept a notification it crashes. But, i repeat, not always. Sometimes when it wants and it's so frustrating!! Have you any ideas?

Comment: use if intent.hasExtra() to check if you have correct extras. if true then proceed. this might fix the issue

Comment: Where have i to put it? in onCreate()? can you show me how? i never use this for check

Comment: after - "if (intent != null) {"

Comment: Also write code how you are sending broadcast.